# Scrollbar not working on Tkinter Canvas. Can someone suggest what am I missing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've been building a tkinter window and I require to build a table inside the frame. I am using Python 3.4.1. I've googled and visited lot of question on SO, but still have not been able to sort this out. My problem is that the scrollbar doesn't work.

Also, the canvas goes out of the frame when the data has too many columns. I want to fix the size of canvas and then the h scroll should take care of it.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    class SimpleTable(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, rows=5, columns =5, data = ''):        

            frame = self.frame = tk.Frame(width = 400)

            #self.frame.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W) 
            self.frame.grid(column = 0, sticky ='w', padx = 30)
            self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, background="black", width=600, height=400, scrollregion=(0,0,1200,800))
            self.hscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
            self.vscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
            self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand = self.hscroll.set)
            self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.vscroll.set)

            self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
            self.hscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
            self.vscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S)

            widgets = []

            for row in range(rows):
                current_row = []
                for column in range(columns):
                    label = tk.Label(self.canvas, text=row+column, borderwidth=0, width=15)                                 
                    label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
                    current_row.append(label)
                widgets.append(current_row)

    def main():
        root = tk.Tk()
        foo=SimpleTable(root)
        root.title('Example')
        root.mainloop()
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The canvas will only scroll objects that are canvas objects. You're adding the labels with `grid`, which means they are *not* canvas objects. To add them to the canvas so that they will scroll you must use `self.canvas.create_window(...)`

Typically, if you are trying to create a scrollable set of widgets, you'll pack or grid them in a frame, then add the frame to the canvas with `create_window`. There are several examples on stackoverflow for how to do this.